# How to trigger directive when property in model is updated? angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've created a dropdownlist, and if a new value is selected from the dropdown, i would like to update the textbox.

i.e. so if movies is selected - then display "movie search" in textbox
     if game is selected - then display "game search in textbox

so far my code isn't triggering my directive when selectedItem property is updated. The directive itself, calls a service method to return the requied text for the textbox.

```
var myAppmodule = angular.module('myApp', []);

myAppmodule.directive("updateTextDependingOnSelectedItem", function () {

return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("selectedItem", function (newValue) {
            angular.element(element).val(scope.mainSearchTextBoxMessage(newValue));
        });

    }

};
});

**Service**
 var mainSearchServices = function(object) {

 return {

    dropdownsearchitems: function () {   // passsing depencies to a factory
      return object.items;
  },
    mainSearchTextBoxMessage: function(selectedItem) {

      // create a swicth statement that returns correct message, make this follow OCP
      return "Select Title"
    }
}
};

**HTML**
<div id="MainPageHeader" ng-controller="mainSearch">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/Logo.png" alt="Image" />
                <div id="loginLinks">
                    sign in / register
                </div>
            <select data-ng-model="selectedItem" data-ng-options="item for item in 
      DropDownItems" class="itemTypesDropDownList">                             
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="headerSearch" 
     update-textdependingonselecteditem="selectedItem" />
                <input type="button" class="searchButton" value="Search" />
            </div>
```

Comment: Change: 'update-textdependingonselecteditem' to `update-text-depending-on-selected-item` in your markup
<br>(or Consider a shorter name, which I'd prefer, personally).

Comment: yep that was the issue,  thanks alot.